# np.isnan() function not solving "divide by zero encountered in true_divide" warning

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

```
Pdict = {"KobeBryant":0,"JoeJohnson":1,"LeBronJames":2,"CarmeloAnthony":3,"DwightHoward":4,"ChrisBosh":5,"ChrisPaul":6,"KevinDurant":7,"DerrickRose":8,"DwayneWade":9}

Salary = np.array([KobeBryant_Salary, JoeJohnson_Salary, LeBronJames_Salary, CarmeloAnthony_Salary, DwightHoward_Salary, ChrisBosh_Salary, ChrisPaul_Salary, KevinDurant_Salary, DerrickRose_Salary, DwayneWade_Salary])

Games = np.array([KobeBryant_G, JoeJohnson_G, LeBronJames_G, CarmeloAnthony_G, DwightHoward_G, ChrisBosh_G, ChrisPaul_G, KevinDurant_G, DerrickRose_G, DwayneWade_G])
```

```
plr =[]

for v in Pdict.values():
    for s in Salary:
        for g in Games:
            if np.isnan(g[v]) == True: continue
            z = np.round(np.divide(s[v], Games[v]), 2)
    plr.append(z)

print(plr)
print(type(z))
```

Im trying to make a new matrix called plr, there is a zero in Games[] and Im trying to make it skip it instead of giving me that error. I found the np.isnan() but it seems to do nothing here. If I run the code with or without that line, it still gives me the runtime warning. Im not sure what Im doing wrong with it or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think that you want to divide s[v] with g[v], like this: 
`z = np.round(np.divide(s[v], g[v]), 2)`


And `if np.isnan(g[v]) == True:` is same as `if np.isnan(g[v]):`

Comment: Ive changed the code to this:



`plr =[]

for v in Pdict.values():
    for s in Salary:
        for g in Games:
            if np.isnan(g[v]): continue
            z = np.round(np.divide(s[v], g[v]), 2)
    plr.append(z)

print(plr)
print(type(z))`


But it still 'div by 0'. I did find this, but dont really understand it:

`np.divide(10, i, where=i!=0)`

PS, sry for bad formatting, idk how to fix it.